# How to get a list of combinations in z3py?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I have a list in python of integers like this:

```
myList = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57]
```

I want to get Z3 to output various sets or lists of numbers which are all members of myList... Essentially, I want to use Z3 to get additional lists of numbers which all exist in myList but are in various different orders. Put differently, I want to get various outputs from Z3 which contain numbers in the set myList above.

I am having trouble doing this with Z3py because I do not know how to have z3 return a list or a set as the model when I call `s.model()`, assuming `s = Solver()`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from z3 import *

myList = [97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57]

s = Solver ()
pick = []
for (i, v) in enumerate(myList):
  b = Bool ('pick_%d' % i)
  s.add(b == b)
  pick += [(b, v)]

while (s.check() == sat):
    m = s.model()

    chosen = []
    block  = []
    for (p, v) in pick:
        if m.eval(p, model_completion=True):
            chosen += [v]
            block.append(Not(p))
        else:
            block.append(p)

    print chosen
    s.add(Or(block))
```

Note that this will print `2^n` solutions where `n` is the number of elements in your list; so it'll take a while to finish if `n` is large!

Comment: How on earth did you learn this? I've never even seen evail() used before and also your usage of the tuples is surprising to me,

Comment: Can you explain the b == b constraint? I don't understand it.

Comment: You either need `s.add(b==b)` or pass the `model_completion=True` argument to `eval`. (I did both; but you actually only need one of those things. Having both doesn't hurt.) Otherwise the solver doesn't know anything about the boolean as there are no constraints on it to start with. `s.add(b==b)` is a cheap way of telling the solver: "hey I have this variable with no constraints on it." Note that calling `Bool` does nothing to the `Solver` instance, so you need to make it aware of it somehow. This is one way of doing it.

Comment: Oh I see.. So you're just adding these values into the solver's workspace so-to-speak, without any particular constraints.